# Is there a way to hide url query params when using GET request?

Tags: django, rest, post, get

I have a page on website with many filters/settings, all of them are stored in JSON object. And this page is displaying live data, so performance is important.

Currently I'm sending POST request to fetch data, but I know it's not the best solution and breaking REST principles.

So there is pros and cons for both solutions:

`GET`

Pros:

- Can use cache (good for performance, which is important)
- Good with REST
- Clear for user, he can see all of his settings directly in the url.

Cons:

- With so much filters and settings final url can become very long, that's not what I want and I think that's a bad for users.

`POST`

Pros:

- Clean url, no distracting users
- I can just do `queryset.filter(**request.data.items())`, It's not really safe tho.

Cons:

- Can't use caching

### So my question is, which way to choose, and if it is GET, can I hide query string somehow or hash it and decode on the backend?

Comment: Why would long URLs be bad for users? The entire idea is that you can share the URL, and thus have the same filtering. You can also use `queryset.filter(**request.query_params.items())`, but that would be similarly very unsafe.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem May be it's just me. I don't really like when URL is too long, also isn't there a url length cap? 
Also I don't sure that url share will work because each of users have "templates" with certain settings, they storing in the db/

Comment: well if the template should not be available, it should return a 404 for that.

Comment: Length cap is more than 2,000 chars, it does not matter how long is the URL, you can built a clean url and make it shareable, so I would not use POST, especially if users want to bookmark or share them

Comment: @GaëtanGR What did you mean by saying "build a clean url", can you give me an example?